# PHP function works, but the page shows blank

Tags: php, html, function

I'm building a photoalbum. You can upload some images, which will be resized, made a record for in the database, etc.. This part works.

Then I wanted to give the photoalbum a thumbnail, to make it look nice in the overview. ([This is the photoalbum-overview](http://www.kbobaarlo.nl/media.php)) I think it is more user-friendly to automatically generate a thumbnail from a uploaded file, so I made a function for resizing and cropping the image, but there it goes wrong...

When I proceed to the php-page with the function, I get a blank screen, as if there is something wrong, but there isn't, as the function still cropped and resized the thumbnail image. Also, any other functions called happened to work, but I still get a blank screen.

And when I erase the cropping/resizing function from the file, everything shows up again, so however everything works, this function still appears to be the problem!

This is the function I am talking about:

`function uploadthumb($path1, $path2, $path3, $path4)
{`

```
$info = getimagesize($path1);
$breedte = $info[0];
$hoogte = $info[1];

if($hoogte <= $breedte)
{
$pseudobreedte = $hoogte*(100/124); 
$margin1 = ($breedte-$pseudobreedte)/2;
$margin2 = $breedte-$pseudobreedte;

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 124);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,0,0,100,124,$pseudobreedte,$hoogte); //nr. 1
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,$path2,90);

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 124);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$margin1,0,100,124,$pseudobreedte,$hoogte); //nr. 1
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,$path3,90);

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 124);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$margin2,0,100,124,$pseudobreedte,$hoogte); //nr. 1
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,$path4,90);        
}
else{
$pseudohoogte = $breedte*(124/100); 
$margin1 = ($hoogte-$pseudohoogte)/2;
$margin2 = $hoogte-$pseudohoogte;
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 124);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,0,0,100,124,$breedte,$pseudohoogte); //nr. 1
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,$path2,90);

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 124);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,0,$margin1,100,124,$breedte,$pseudohoogte); //nr. 1
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,$path3,90);

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 124);
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,0,$margin2,100,124,$breedte,$pseudohoogte); //nr. 1
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,$path4,90);
}
}
```

Comment: most likely you are outputting other stuff before the header() call and you don't have error reporting turned on to see the "headers already sent" warning.

Comment: try setting error reporting on .. add these lines at the beginning of your php code.. `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

Comment: Thanx man!!! I now see what I did wrong.. I shouldn't have used the header() function, I thought it defined the content-type of the thumbnail, but it doesn't.. It does define the content-type of the page I am viewing, which makes sense that it wouldn't work out.. Oops :-)

I deleted the header() functions, and now it works.. 

Thanks again, I really didn't come to the answer myself!

Comment: Also, you should only have to do `$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 124);` once

Comment: Shouldn't have to output the Content-type header more than once either.

Comment: @stefan: he's specifying a path in the function call, so it's saving to a file, not outputting directly to the client (unless those $path variables are empty/null).

Comment: Marc's right. I'm just saving a thumbnail in a specific directory. This question is solved now ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was pretty simple.. I wanted to save three thumbnails, and the only thing I was doing wrong, was calling the header() function each time. I thought header() specified the image I was saving, but as a matter of fact it specifies the content-type of the document itself, which made the page turn blank.